# Lua - Obfuscate code capprime

Tags: lua

So, I want to obfuscate my lua code. I search for lua obfuscators on google and this site comes http://www.capprime.com/CapprimeLuaObfuscator/CapprimeLuaObfuscator.aspx. Also, I've seen many other site mention it too as a good obfuscator. But when I copy and paste my code to see that... the exact same code is generated. Why is that so? You can also test this by giving a sample input, that same output is generated. Are any good obfuscators around behind this? Thanks

Comment: What sort of "obfuscation" are you looking for? That site seems to replace function and variable names in some quick tests (and does that badly even replacing their names inside strings). So anyone that mentions that as a good obfuscator is likely wildly exaggerating or working with *very* *very* specifically written code. I should also mention that most obfuscation is ultimately worthless.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there are no obfuscators for Lua due to the fact that Lua allows you to implement your own obfuscator. Please read the C api of Lua and there you have ways of implementing your own file reader for lua files. By using that approach you can obfuscate/encrypt/decrypt on load of the file.